# How to use custom Vue components in content script when creating browser extension projects using quasar cli (with vite)?

Tags: quasar

When I used quasar cli (with vite) to create a browser extension project and used import xxx from "xxx. vue" in content script, it reported an
error:

> No loader is configured for ". vue" files: src/components/ContentView. vue

I tried adding:

```js
const defineConfig = require("vite"); const vue = require("@vitejs/plugin-vue");
```

And added in build.vitePlugins:

```js
"@vitejs/plugin-vue",           
{             
    include: (path.resolve(__dirname), "./src/components/**"),           
},
```

Unfortunately, it still reports an error